# Enum to String Lookup Object -> has no index Signature

Tags: typescript, enums

I'm trying to map an enum to a String:

```
enum Status {
    NEW = "NEW",
    INPROCESSING = "IN PROCESSING",
    DONE = "DONE"
};

const statusToColor: { [key in Status ]: string } = {
    "NEW": "blue",
    "IN PROCESSING": "yellow",
    "DONE": "green"
}
```

Up to this point everything is fine.
But when I try:

**EDIT: Seems as I simplified the problem to much, as the actual problem still seems to be somewhere else:**

The has no Index error only occurs, when I try to feed "statusToColor" from an Array, like this:

```
const statusArrayToColors = (statusArray: Status[]): string[] => {
    return statusArray.map(status => statusToColor[status])
}
```

In this case

```
statusToColor[status]
```

has no Index signature according to the compiler.

Comment: Did you see my answer? The code you edited fixing the typo works for me.

Answer (score 3):

Your code has a typo. This works for me `Version 2.5.0-dev.20170629`:

```
enum Status {
    NEW = "NEW",
    INPROCESSING = "IN PROCESSING",
    DONE = "DONE"
};

const statusToColor: { [key in Status ]: string } = {
    "NEW": "blue",
    "IN PROCESSING": "yellow",
    "DONE": "green"
}

const color: string = statusToColor[Status.NEW];
```

Check the line of `statusToColor`. To define the type you must use colon `:`, not equal `=`.

Note: [you need at least typescript version 2.4.](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-4.html)

Comment: Its new as of version 2.4 string literals can be used in Enums

Comment: Thanks for the fast response!
I simplified the problem to much, the actual error seems to be somewhere else. Would you mind to take a look on the updated question?